# Download/Copy GIT Repo into SVN Repo (without history)

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, tortoisesvn

How does one pull/download/copy an existing GIT Repo (history is unimportant) into a new SVN branch?

Our R&D guys use GIT, as it makes sense for them, as for us commissioners/implementers we have always used SVN and have no need to use GIT. So what I need to do is somehow get a bit-for-bit copy of the data in the GIT repo pushed into a new SVN branch.

We have always used TortoiseSVN as our client and what I've tried so far is putting a URL in the repo browser to access the git stuff. But the result is an invalid XML response.